# Javascript offsetleft, offsettop, offsetwidth and offsetheight

Tags: javascript, offsetwidth, offsetheight

Can anyone tell me how Javascript methods "offsetleft", "offsettop", "offsetwidth" and "offsetheight" works in IE? How can we make them work properly in IE? 
Please tell me a suitable function for the same.

Thanks in advance !

This is my code...which gives different result in IE.

```
function getContainerWidth(container){
 var outerWrapWidth = container.offsetWidth;
     return outerWrapWidth;
 }
 function getContainerHeight(container){
 var outerWrapHeight = container.offsetHeight;
 return outerWrapHeight;
 }   
 function findPosX(ele){     
 var left = ele.offsetLeft;
 return left;
 }
 function findPosY(ele){
 var top = ele.offsetTop;
 return top;
 }  
var obj = document.getElementById('obj1');
console.log('width : '+getContainerWidth(obj))
console.log('height : '+getContainerHeight(obj))
console.log('left : '+findPosX(obj))
console.log('top : '+findPosY(obj))
```

Comment: Can you post the code your working on

Comment: Sure..I have posted my code which gives me different output in IE